# grunt-typescript doesn't produce js files in specified `dest`

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gruntjs

I have the following directory structure :

```
root
|
|_ package.json
|_ Gruntfile.js
|
|_ javascripts/
   |_ ts/file.ts
```

In the Gruntfile I have this:

```
//Project Config
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    typescript: {
        base: {
            src: ['./javascripts/ts/*.ts'],
            dest: './javascripts/'
        }
    }       
});
```

I expect the js files to be in `javascripts/` directory. However when I run `grunt typescript` , it creates this weird directory structure:

```
root
|
|_ package.json
|_ Gruntfile.js
|
|_ javascripts/
   |_ ts/file.ts
   |_ javascripts/
      |_ ts/
         |_ file.js
```

I expect the compiled `file.js` to appear in the original `javascripts/` directory.
Why is this so? What should I write to get compiled `.js` files in desired folder?

Comment: I wrote grunt-ts. Give it a whirl. Just sayin ;)

Comment: @basarat `grunt-ts` does solve that problem!

Answer (score 5):

Seeing the output I would assume the following will work:

```
typescript: {
    base: {
        src: ['./javascripts/ts/*.ts'],
        dest: '../../javascripts/'
    }
}
```

Personally I authored and maintain `grunt-ts` : https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ts

Comment: +1 for providing a solution that doesn't involve your own software *in addition* to providing a link to your own software

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make use of the `base_path` config:

```
//Project Config
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    typescript: {
        base: {
            src: ['./javascripts/ts/*.ts'],
            dest: './javascripts/',
            options: {
                base_path: './javascripts/ts'
            }
        }
    }       
});
```